# jqPlot hourly graph

Tags: jquery, graph, jqplot

I'd like jqPlot similar to this, http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/date-axes.html

However I'd like to do it hourly. I've got 2 weeks of data that I'd like displayed hourly and would like the x-axis to display somewhat like this:

```
8am 9am 10am ... 11pm   12am 1am 2am 3am ...  
|----June 1, 2012----| |----June 2, 2012----|
```

Is there a way to do this?

The problem with doing a naive modification of the example is that the x-axis label becomes unreadable, even when using small amounts of data.

[image: Axis Overwrite]

Naive modification of code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var line1=[... data snipped...];
  var plot2 = $.jqplot('chart2', [line1], {
      title:'Customized Date Axis', 
      axes:{
        xaxis:{
          renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer, 
          tickOptions:{formatString:'%b %#d, %#I %p'},
          min:'June 1, 2012 8:00AM', 
          tickInterval:'1 hour'
        }
      },
      series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
  });
});​
```

See JSFiddle for live editing of the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/AqFTV/

I konw that I can change the tickOptions formatstring, but I'm unable to find documentation on that.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest that in order to improve readability of your graph [to rotate your ticks example here.](http://www.jqplot.com/tests/rotated-tick-labels.php)

As it goes to tick format all you can do you can find in [docs under DateAxisRenderer plugin here.](http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/plugins/jqplot-dateAxisRenderer-js.html)